# MySQLi UPDATE has an error with one column

Tags: php, mysqli

The query I'm using (from php) is

```
"UPDATE articles SET
title='".$_POST['title']."',
contents='".$_POST['cont']."', 
category='".$_POST['cat']."', 
desc='".$_POST['desc']."' 
WHERE stitle='".$_POST['stitle']."'";
```

and I get the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='hello' WHERE stitle='banana'' at line 1.

If I remove `desc='".$_POST['desc']."'` the query works. The field 'desc' is varchar(150). I can insert text directly from phpMyAdmin, the field is definitely called 'desc', and `$_POST['desc']` definitely captures a value (I tried using `echo $_POST['desc'];` and a value is passed). I tried changing the code to `desc='test'` and that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is probably in your `$_POST['cat']` value. You should be using a prepared statement with bound parameters

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I changed it to `$tit=$_POST['title'];
  $stit=$_POST['stitle'];
  $cont=$_POST['cont'];
  $desc=$_POST['desc'];
  $cat=$_POST['cat'];` and 
`UPDATE articles SET title='".$tit."', contents='".$cont."', category='".$cat."', desc='".$desc."' WHERE stitle='".$stit."';` same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. I created a new column in the table, copied the information from 'desc' into that column, deleted 'desc'. I ran the query with the new column name, and it works. I don't know what the issue was, but that fixed it.

Comment: Probably the problem are the column name itself. I've updated the answer with escapes to avoid these problems. You can check it if you like.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem are your $_POST['desc'] contains an apostrophe. I recommend you to use on all parameters the function mysqli_real_escape_string (doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Also, try to escape all rows and tables with backticks, to avoid reserved words creating errors.

Your query example looks like this with them:

```
"UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = '".mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', `contents` = '".mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['cont'])."',  `category` = '".mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['cat'])."',  `desc` = '".mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['desc'])."'  WHERE `stitle` = '".mysqli::real_escape_string($_POST['stitle'])."'";
```

If you are programming with procedural style calls to mysqli functions, use:

```
"UPDATE `articles` SET `title` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title'])."', `contents` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cont'])."',  `category` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['cat'])."',  `desc` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['desc'])."'  WHERE `stitle` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['stitle'])."'";
```

(Obviosuly, replace $link with the variable initialized when you do mysqli_connect())

Using these function, you can avoid these errors, and, also, a lot of SQL exploits. There's no required if the variable contains an integer, but, you always need to check the data passed to the SQL engine to avoid problems.

Is a good practice, to have some checks, for example, testing who integer vars contains integers, or doing escape with mysqli::real_escape_string. And, if something are incorrect on the input data, halt the process and don't request the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It generated the error `Non-static method mysqli::real_escape_string() cannot be called statically`. I'd have thought that it wouldn't have posted when I remove the 'desc' column.

Comment: I corrected the real_escape_string code as per [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp), and got the original error again.

Comment: If you check documentation, the function have another form of being called. If you're using procedural style on your code, replace all mysqli::real_escape_string() with mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapestr), where $link are the variable who you've created on mysqli_connect(), and $escapestr the $_POST var to be cleared.

Comment: Try to escape the rows name with `` (example: `desc` = ....). I've corrected the answer with that syntax.

Comment: I did, and I'm back to the original error. I'm sure it's taking issue with the column called 'desc', but I can't work out why. It's set up the same way as two other columns that work. It's definitely called 'desc', I can query MySqli and return the information in 'desc'. It just doesn't seem to want to update.